# ant copy a list of files evenly across multiple folders

Tags: ant

I'm using ant to drive some test automation.  I have a flattened folder that has about 100 files of the same type.  I'd like to spread these files across 4 folders evenly to spread the execution across a few machines.  So the project would create the four folders and then run through the hundred files passing one file to a folder and then continue on. file 1 goes to folder 1, 2 to 2, 3 to 3, 4 to 4, 5 to 1, etc.  The names and numbers of files will fluctuate. I can write a small utility to do this but it would be simplier for maintanace if I could do this as part of the ant execution.

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses  the [groovy ANT task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) which integrates very well into an ANT build:

```
<project name="demo" default="distribute">

    <target name="bootstrap">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy-all.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.1.0-beta-1/groovy-all-2.1.0-beta-1.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="distribute">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>
        <fileset id="srcFiles" dir="build/src" includes="*.txt"/>
        <groovy>
            def i = 0
            project.references.srcFiles.each {
                ant.copy(file:it, todir:"build/dir/${i % 4}", verbose:true)
                i++
            }
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- Use a modulus operation to distribute files contained in the ANT fileset, into different directories
- The "bootstrap" target is used to download and install the 3rd party task jar from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.groovy%7Cgroovy-all%7C2.1.0-beta-1%7Cjar)